Deserializar json a Object cambiando el nombre de las propiedades
tengo el siguiente escenario, tengo un json con la siguiente estructura

requiero deseriaizarla a un objeto que tiene la siguiente estructura

La duda es como hago para que detecte la diferencia en la propiedades y genere el objeto basado en el json orinal?
Nota, estoy trabajando con c# .net 8

probaste con anotaciones?

El código como texto, nunca como imagen. Nadie va a responder tu pregunta, porque, así como está se cierran y se elimina

Hola Wilson, bienvenido, tanto los códigos como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y la modifiques para evitar recibir votos negativos y/o que sea cerrada.

De manera estándar podrías usar el atributo JsonPropertyName para especificar el nombre que le correspondería a tu propiedad, por ejemplo:
public class MiObjeto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccesToken { get; set; }
}

La idea del ejemplo es que en este caso la propiedad AccesToken tenga su representación en el json en  la clave access_token. Finalmente:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{ \"access_token\": \"en el json me llamo access_token\" }";
        MiObjeto miObjeto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MiObjeto>(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"AccesToken: {miObjeto.AccesToken}");
    }
}

Salida:
> AccesToken: en el json me llamo access_token

En caso que uses NewtonSoft el atributo sería [JsonProperty("access_token")]

Hola Patricio, mil gracias por tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda, y tambien tendré en cuenta las observaciones de los demás para futuras consultas.
